# Squarespace: Full Paypal integration with Squarespace

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, squarespace

Squarespace currently only supports Stripe as a payment platform. I am looking for a way to fully integrate Paypal as the go-to way to pay (one of the reasons for this is that Stripe’s checkout page is currently in english and that is a complete no-go for our client) with full inventory sync (Squarespace with Paypal), tracking payments in Squarespace(!), etc. — I basically want to reproduce the full e-commerce process behind Squarespace, only not via Stripe, but via Paypal. Whenever I checkout on Squarespace, the whole cart should be sent to Paypal, processed there, the customer pays, is sent back to Squarespace and Squarespace should be aware of the changes/purchase/payment and update the inventory.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have googled extensively and am aware of threads like http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/16845/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-paypal-with-squarespace , this is just simply not enough + opens a ton of new issues (a custom Paypal button is needed whenever a new product is added to Squarespace’s inventory, for example).

I’d appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: you need to learn how to make API calls. be careful as there are implications with security and compliance depending on what type of data or where you are doing this. don't build a payment gateway module with an API unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible except that it doesn't look like Squarespace provides tools to build in custom payment gateways.  Their developer section covers how to customize the design aspects of your site, but I don't see anything about custom modules or any way to build in things like shipping calculators, payment gateways, etc.

I just skimmed through it pretty quickly, though, so you may want to double check or just ask them directly.  That's a common issue with hosted platforms, though.  If they don't provide it and don't provide a way for you to build it yourself and plug it into their platform, your only option is to change platforms.

There are plenty of nice shopping cart platforms that work with PayPal, though.  If you're open to looking at a different one I would recommend WordPress + WooCommerce.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. **Thank you** for your answer, Andrew — appreciated. :) We ended up using Shopify in the end, since it was much more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible as of May 2016 and I can tell you that I'm fairly sure you won't see this in built in to Squarespace as an option anytime soon.

Squarespace's Commerce backend is designed for Stripe so much of the "checkout" process is locked down. However, use the [Squarespace Developer Mode](http://developers.squarespace.com) you're free to hack up the Products user interface and roll your own integrations and extensions.

Keep in mind, if you go this route you would be bypassing Squarespace's backend Commerce functionality and would be handling that via Paypal. A simplistic approach to this functionality can be executed using Paypal's embedded buttons and related functionality. It's not ideal, but unfortunately that's all we have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Squarespace offers an irreversible "developer mode" that allows you to completely customize the code for your site and even edit locally. Once you enable this feature, you are no longer able to change your selected theme (as you have shifted the liability from their end to yours, they are simply hosting your site at this point). You are able to use all of the drag and drop features, tools, etc - just not change the theme/template.

Furthermore, **as of March, 2017 Squarespace offers PayPal integration as well as Stripe.** Please reference the article below for more information:

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545517-Accepting-PayPal